# Delete Particular Contact Form 7 Hook

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a question regarding to the contact form 7.

My question is Which hook use when the user delete particular contact form from the WordPress admin?

I require to use that hook for delete some details from the database.

Comment: Not getting exactly, what you want?

Comment: @PPL when user delete particular contact form not the plugin then Which hook or filter can i use to do some stuff?

Comment: Please check my updated answer and reference url.

Comment: You can also refer: http://hookr.io/plugins/contact-form-7/4.5.1/hooks/#index=l

Comment: @PPL i referred this but didnot get the correct hook.

Comment: There is no hook available for  contact form 7  delete.

Answer (score 0):

CF7 forms are stored as a custom post type so you can simply use the delete_post hook: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/delete_post